# Angular development environment not working as expected after upgrade to Angular 9 and 10

Tags: angular, rxjs, settimeout, angular-ivy, angular10

I work on a pretty large angular project. We have been on angular 8 for the most part of 2020, and postponed upgrading to angular 9 and 10 because last time we tried upgrading, the application did not feel right. Therefore, we made the decision to use the summer for upgrading and fixing the issues we were experiencing. I weren't involved in the actual upgrade, and the guy responsible has gone on vacation.

There are a few issues which hits our development environment, which we do not experience in our production build:

- **setTimeout**-functions have stopped working. A timeout of 1 second might actually take 30 seconds. Same with different **rxjs** alternatives, for example **delay**(). It makes it seem like every function that uses a setTimeout() freezes or hangs.
- We have lost hot reload on save.
- Chrome devtools feels very laggy.
- The app overall feels unpredictable.
- Recompiling the application on save is very slow.

And again, our production build does not seem to suffer from these issues, especially not the problems with setTimeout.

I have tried looking at our angular.json and tsconfig-configurations and turning off Ivy, but with little luck. Also, i am running the latest version of Node.js, and have tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json multiple times.

If anyone has heard of similar things happening, or have any advice, it would be greatly appreciated. Could there be dependencies that are causing problems for the Ivy compiler?

**Angular.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "hf-client": {
      "i18n": {
        "locales": {
          "nb": {
            "translation": "src/assets/i18n/messages.nb.xlf",
            "baseHref": ""
          }
        }
      },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
            "aot": true,
                        "outputPath": "Static",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "i18nFile": "src/assets/i18n/messages.nb.xlf",
                        "i18nLocale": "nb",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "src/styles"
                            ]
                        },
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/app.config.js",
                            "src/Web.config",
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins",
                                "output": "/skins"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes",
                                "output": "/themes"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins",
                                "output": "/plugins"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "src/app/shared/plugins/tinymce-mention",
                                "output": "/plugins/mention"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "src/assets/i18n/langsTinyMCE",
                                "output": "/langs"
                            }
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                            "node_modules/angular2-toaster/toaster.css",
                            "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/dist/all.css",
                            "node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
                            "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
                            "src/styles/app.scss"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                },
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/index.html",
                                    "with": "src/index.release.html"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true
                        },
                        "hmr": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "hf-client:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "hf-client:build:production"
                        },
                        "hmr": {
                            "hmr": true,
                            "browserTarget": "hf-client:build:hmr"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "hf-client:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "scripts": [],
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "src/styles"
                            ]
                        },
                        "styles": [],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/Web.config",
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins",
                                "output": "/skins"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes",
                                "output": "/themes"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins",
                                "output": "/plugins"
                            },
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "src/assets/i18n/langsTinyMCE",
                                "output": "/langs"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "hf-client-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "hf-client:serve"
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "hf-client"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
 {
      "files": [],
      "references": [
        {
          "path": "./src/tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
          "path": "./src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        }
      ]
    }
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
{
  "name": "hf-client",
  "version": "5.6.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8080",
    "serve": "ng serve --port 8080",
    "serve:hmr": "ng serve --port 8080 --configuration hmr",
    "build:no-prod": "ng build",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build:analyze": "ng build --stats-json",
    "postbuild": "node post_build.js",
    "stats": "webpack-bundle-analyzer Static/stats.json",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "test-headless": "ng test --code-coverage --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    "test:once": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --browsers ChromeHeadless",
    "test-no-sm": "ng test --sourceMap=false --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "nightwatch-test": "node nightwatch.conf.js && node node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch -c nightwatch.conf.js",
    "nw": "npm run nightwatch-test -- -e chrome-local",
    "nwh": "npm run nightwatch-test -- -e chrome-local-headless",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points && ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.6.2",
    "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.6.2",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.6.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.2.7",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.7.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^4.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^2.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^5.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.3",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^4.16.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^2.5.0",
    "@w11k/ngx-componentdestroyed": "^4.1.5",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.14",
    "angular-gridster2": "8.3.0",
    "angular-text-input-autocomplete": "^0.3.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cldr-data": "^32.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "globalize": "^1.4.2",
    "inputmask": "^3.3.11",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.1",
    "ngx-contextmenu": "^5.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "sticky-sidebar-v2": "^1.0.1",
    "tinymce": "^4.9.8",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "~1.1.0",
    "selenium-download": "^2.0.14",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:15631/"
}
```

Comment: Do you experience the issues on angular 10 or angular 9?

Comment: We first upgraded to angular 9 and tried it for about a week. We were experiencing the same issues then, so we can assume that the issues were introduced in version 9.